# NodeJS include header and footer without EJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I was hoping someone may be able to assist me with NodeJS. Iv recently started developing my site using NodeJS.

**The problem:**

im looking for a way to send my documents as *a header, content, footer* style so it reduces repeating code for each section.

I have a **public folder** setup so i can include Js, CSS and common files etc...

```
self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This all works, however im unsure about how to implement a simple way to join the file content. Every source iv looked at online suggests the "correct" way to do it is via a package called [EJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) templates.

So im looking for something similar to this implementation in EJS:

```
<header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</header>

<footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>
```

However, the service im hosting on does not support EJS, so is it possible to do something like this?

```
self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('header.html')+self.cache_get('index.html')+self.cache_get('footer.html') );
        };
```

Is there another simple way to separate header, content and footer to make it simpler to develop website with dynamic content?

Comment: What do you mean does not support EJS? It is just a node module. There are also plenty of other template engines. I like [doT](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html).

Comment: Im using openshift and do not have access to the server-side console to use NPM so installing nodes on nodejs seems unclear, the website states that nodes can be included by modify the package.json but doesent mention exactly what format to use to enable them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could write your own js to do this, at your current level I don't recommend it (other than for learning and experimental purposes). This is why node is so powerful, because you don't have to reinvent the wheel all the time. You noted that you are using openshift, and that you cannot use modules. **This is where you are incorrect**.

[This link](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/dependency-management.html) explains how to use npm with openshift. It would be extremely silly for any node.js hosting service to not allow package integration. To briefly explain how this works, you essentially install your packages in your local environment using the `--save` flag. This will update your local `package.json` file with details about your dependencies and versions. When you push your repo to your host, it looks at this file, and takes care of the dependency installation for you.

On this note, if you are going to continue using node.js, you should have a good read about package management. https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/packages

Comment: Good answer and very helpful thanks for taking the time. Iv been reading it and in the file it has a dependencies section, however although the format is simple it doesent state how to find which version numbers of a particular dependency is acceptable.... "express": "~3.4.4" is there some sort of list of current versions available to know..?

Comment: When you use something like `npm install express --save` it will automatically choose the latest stable version for you. Any version you can download locally will be acceptable on your host, as it is all just more javascript.

Answer (score 4):

[Trumpet](https://github.com/substack/node-trumpet/) should let you do this. Something like this may work:

```
const trumpet = require('trumpet')
const tr = trumpet()

tr.pipe(res)

const header = tr.select('header').createWriteStream()
fs.createReadStream('header.html').pipe(header)

const footer = tr.select('footer').createWriteStream()
fs.createReadStream('footer.html').pipe(footer)

fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(tr)
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful actually was easier to get working than EJS, if i could  upvote more than once i would.

Comment: I'm so glad! :D